# C++ - Creating Binary Search Tree Class, one Node disappears after rotate

Tags: c++, rotation, binary-tree

I am trying to create a custom Binary Search Tree, and I have everything done except for the rotate function, which seems to be not moving a node over. The rotate function only gets called when a node is searched and found, and if the node has a right child. For simplicity I will only add the functions that are used in this, to make it shorter:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MRBST {
public:
    MRBST();
    ~MRBST();

    void push(const T &);
    bool search(const T &);
    void PrintPreorder();
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;

        Node (const T & theData, Node *lt, Node *rt) 
        : data(theData), left(lt), right(rt) {}
    };
    Node *root;

    void push(const T &, Node * &) const;
    void remove(const T &, Node * &) const;
    Node* findMin(Node *t) const {
        if (t == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (t->left == NULL) {
            return t;
        }
        return findMin(t->left);
    }
    void preorder(Node * &);
    bool search(const T &, Node *);
    Node* findNode(const T & x, Node * t) {
        if (t == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (x < t->data) {
            return findNode(x, t->left);
        } else if (x > t->data) {
            return findNode(x, t->right);
        } else if (x == t->data) {
            return t;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    void rotate(Node *);
};

template <typename T>
void MRBST<T>::PrintPreorder() {
    preorder(root);
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void MRBST<T>::preorder(Node * & t) {
    if (t != NULL) {
        cout << t->data << endl;
        preorder(t->left);
        preorder(t->right);
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool MRBST<T>::search(const T & x) {
    if (search(x, root)) {
        Node *temp = findNode(x, root);
        rotate(temp);
        return true;            
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MRBST<T>::rotate(Node * k1) {
    if (k1->right == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        Node *temp = k1->right;
        k1->right = temp->left;
        temp->left = k1;
    }
}


template <typename T>
bool MRBST<T>::search(const T & x, Node *t) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        return false;
    } else if (x < t->data) {
        return  search(x, t->left);
    } else if (x > t->data) {
        return search(x, t->right);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have a simple testing file that just adds some numbers to the tree, and then searches, followed by a print out in Preordering.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MRBST.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    MRBST<int> binaryTree;
    binaryTree.push(5);
    binaryTree.push(20);
    binaryTree.push(3);
    binaryTree.push(3);
    binaryTree.push(4);
    binaryTree.push(22);
    binaryTree.push(17);
    binaryTree.push(18);
    binaryTree.push(8);
    binaryTree.push(9);
    binaryTree.push(1);
    binaryTree.PrintPreorder();
    cout << endl;
    binaryTree.search(17);
    binaryTree.PrintPreorder();
    cout << endl;

}
```

With the output looking a something like this:

5
3
1
4
20
17
8
9
18
22

5
3
1
4
20
17
8
9
22

If anyone could give some insight into what is going wrong with my rotate function, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing `rotate` on search? It should be read-only.

You're losing the node because of that.

Look at your `rotate`:

```
    Node *temp = k1->right;
    k1->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = k1;
```

Assume k1=x has right=y and left=z, look step by step:

```
    Node *temp = k1->right;
```

temp =k1->right = y, k1 = x, k1->left = z

```
    k1->right = temp->left;
```

k1->right = ?, k1->left = z, temp = y

```
    temp->left = k1;
```

k1->right = ?, k1->left = z, temp->left = x.

Now - where did Y go? You lost it.

Comment: just something that must be done in our assignment. How is it read-only?

Comment: @Muller - search returns `true` if found, `false` otherwise. What assignment?

Comment: @Muller, actually now that I look at it - I don't know what your `search` is supposed to be doing. Anyway, your `rotate` is flawed.

Comment: Wouldn't k1->right just be whatever temp->left is? So since temp = k1->right, then its the same thing as k1->right = k1->right->left. If k1->right->left is NULL then wouldn't that just set k1->right as NULL?

Comment: @Muller - where did you get that from? assignment copies the value, doesn't create another name to the variable. Doing `temp = k1->right` doesn't make `temp` synonym to `k1->right`!

Comment: however temp is a pointer, so would that just mean that temp points to k1->right?

Comment: @Muller, yes, it does. But noone points to it, so it is lost for you.

Comment: How is it lost? If temp is pointing to it, then it still is present in memory, even though k1->right is no longer pointing to it.

Comment: @Muller - `temp` dies once you exit the function. At that point - no-one points to it any longer. It's still in the memory, it's just you cannot access it any more. I think you're confusing a lot with some other programming language (Java?), because you seem to be missing the basics of how C++ works with memory.

Comment: temp is only used as a placeholder, nothing more so the fact it is deleted once the function is exited does not matter.
EDIT: Looking at it, I noticed it does matter, however what would avoid this from occuring? All the references I have seen of a rotation does the same thing.

Comment: @Muller - `temp` has to be assigned to someone. You probably missed a line or something like that. I'm guessing it is supposed to replace `k1` in its place.

Comment: I have been staring at this for a good week now, looking at other code references, however they all say the same thing, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Muller - that's a good time to start using a debugger. Sometimes one just can't figure it out without it, happens to everyone.

Comment: I have been using the debugger this entire time. I have realized though, if I do k1=NULL in rotate and don't do anything else, nothing happens at all. So it seems to be my pointers, but beyond that I'm not sure

Comment: @Muller - by default parameters in C++ are passed by value. I think you need to pass a reference, because you need to change your `k1` here. Again, I'm guessing, but I'm pretty sure you're coming from Java. You're making very common mistakes. Read about the differences between the languages.

Comment: I know nothing of Java, nor have I touched the language. Passing a reference does nothing unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but after changing it to a reference for the 20th time actually worked. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at your rotate() function, step by step, to see whether it does what you want it to do or not.